# PFBC form not showing validation errors

Tags: php, validation, pfbc

I am working on an implementation of PFBC. For this, I wrote an extension that basically runs a login form. When the user cannot be logged in, I want to display an error message. As I understand it, PFBC should show this automatically, but somehow it does not.

I have tripped the user class to always return false, and verified that I do reach the right section of the implementation. I would therefor expect the form to display *Error: Invalid Email Address / Password* but I only get an empty form. Could someone help me to get this to work?

This is the class extension

namespace PFBC;

```
class jf_form extends Form
  {  
  function login_form()
   {
$this->addElement(new Element\HTML('<legend>Login</legend>'));
$this->addElement(new Element\Hidden("form", "login"));
$this->addElement(new Element\Email("Email Address:", "Email", array(
    "required" => 1
)));
$this->addElement(new Element\Password("Password:", "Password", array(
    "required" => 1
)));
$this->addElement(new Element\Checkbox("", "Remember", array(
    "1" => "Remember me"
)));
$this->addElement(new Element\Button("Login"));
$this->addElement(new Element\Button("Cancel", "button", array(
    "onclick" => "history.go(-1);"
)));
$this->render();
}
}
```

and the implementation:
    use PFBC\jf_form;
    use PFBC\Element;

```
// Initiate forms
$formi = new PFBC\jf_form();

// Test login
if(jf_form::isValid("login", false)) 
  {
  // form was submitted
  $user = new user();
  if($user->login($_POST["Email"], $_POST["Password"])) 
    {
    jf_form::clearValues("login");
    }
  else 
{
    jf_form::setError("login", "Error: Invalid Email Address / Password");
    $formi->login_form();
echo "false";
}
  }
else
  {
  // create login form
  $formi->login_form();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the problem. The script assumes a specific form ID to be set. When initiating, one has to pass the form ID and use this throughout.

```
$formi = new PFBC\jf_form("jflogin");
  if(jf_form::isValid("jflogin", false))
    {
```